# Compare between objects raise compilation error according to order

Tags: c++

I've created a `Point` class and overload his `operator==`, and a `PointSet` class that has an array of pointers to `Point` objects.

Now, when i want to compare between two object I'm running in to unexplained compilation error when I'm tring to compare A==B but not when B==A.
i.e when im fliping the order of the object the function work as ecxpected.
I didnt find any logic between this two cases.

This is Point and PointSet classes (diffrenet header files)

```
class Point{
public:
    Point(int x, int y);
    ~Point();
    bool operator==(const Point& point);

private:
    int _x, _y;
};

class PointSet
{
public :
    PointSet(const size_t startLen);
    ~PointSet();
    int contains(const Point *point) const

private:
    Point **_pointArray;
    size_t _size;
};
```

this is the implementation of the `operator==`

```
bool Point::operator ==(const Point& point){
    return (this->_x == point.get_x() && this->_y == point.get_y());
}
```

And this is the function where the problem occur

```
int PointSet::contains(const Point *point) const{
    for (int i=0; i<_size;i++){
        if (*point == *_pointArray[i]){ <-----HERE 
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

this ISN'T an error `if(*_pointArray[i] == *point)`

the compilation error is "Can't compare structures"

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: Your operator== should be a const function.

Comment: `get_x()` and `get_y()` are declared as `const` functions?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes they are.

Comment: @limitless Post a [MCVE] please, before wasting everybodies time here.

Comment: To make it clear, my code now work well, i just want ot know why when im flipping the comparetion i get an compilation error.
why is the unvote for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operator== should be a const function

Comment: @limitless then do change it and make it const

Comment: Ok its solved the problem, but why consting the function helped?

Comment: @limitless because the argument to the contains function is const.  Since the operator== function wasn't const, there was no matching operator== function to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement

`bool operator==(const Point& lhs, const PointSet& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }`

as a friend member function. Also include:

`bool operator==(const PointSet& lhs, const Point& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }`.

This is the way you guarantee it will work.

More about this can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Comment: _"This is the way you guarantee it will work"_ Nope.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why not? It's not a permutative operator, and one includes both directions, and then it works.

Comment: At least not with non const `get_x()` and `get_y()` functions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Honestly, I'm not sure about the `const` part. But I never had to const anything with `operator==()`, and it works. References don't show this, like the one I attached. They don't use `const` expect for access operators, like `operator[]`.

Comment: The ball is back to the OP to provide a [MCVE], at least without it's unclear what they're asking about.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed!